# Create multiple files from unique values of a column using inbuilt libraries of python

Tags: python

I started learning python and was wondering if there was a way to create multiple files from unique values of a column. I know there are 100's of ways of getting it done through pandas. But I am looking to have it done through inbuilt libraries. I couldn't find a single example where its done through inbuilt libraries.

Here is the sample csv file data:

```
uniquevalue|count
a|123
b|345
c|567
d|789
a|123
b|345
c|567
```

Sample output file:

```
a.csv
    uniquevalue|count
    a|123
    a|123

b.csv
    b|345
    b|345
```

I am struggling with looping on unique values in a column and then print them out. Can someone explain with logic how to do it ? That will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a sample how the result should looks like when using your input sample?

Comment: @iroth Added sample on how the result should look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

header = []
data = defaultdict(list)

DELIMITER = "|"

with open("inputfile.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=DELIMITER)

    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0:
            header = row
        else:
            key = row[0]
            data[key].append(row)


for key, value in data.items():
    filename = f"{key}.csv"
    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=DELIMITER)

        rows = [header] + value
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: I get too many values to upack error : 

    key, value = row
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Then your input file does not resemble your output, or there are lines with no values associated

Comment: what if there are more than two columns and I have to specify the column header name ?

Comment: check the edit, works for an indefinite number of columns - at least 1

Answer (score 0):

```py
import csv
with open('sample.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        with open(f"{row[0]}.csv", 'a') as inner:
            writer = csv.writer(
                inner, delimiter='|',
                fieldnames=('uniquevalue', 'count')
            )
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

the task can also be done without using csv module. the lines of the file are read, and with `read_file.read().splitlines()[1:]` the newline characters are stripped off, also skipping the header line of the csv file. with a set a unique collection of inputdata is created, that is used to count number of duplicates and to create the output files.

```
with open("unique_sample.csv", "r") as read_file:
    items = read_file.read().splitlines()[1:]
    for line in set(items):    
        with open(line[:line.index('|')] + '.csv', 'w') as output:
            output.write((line + '\n') * items.count(line))
```